# Adding tilde to datawindow setFilter string

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I've been trying to filter a datawindow by using the argument `product_id = 'Z108-20-6,3~10' and company_id = 14`, but the setFilter function returns -1, which is invalid.

After looking at the docs and some Google search, I've found that the tilde character is an escape character, so, in order to use it as a literal character, I should be using "~~" instead of "~". Using two tildes in the filter argument does change the return value, but doesn't apply the filter correctly (it keeps showing no rows).

How can I SetFilter a datawindow by using a tilde in the filter expression? I`m using PB 12.5.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will fix your issue but something to try.

From the PB help for the SetFilter method.

> The escape keyword designates any character as an escape character (do
>   not use a character that is part of the string you want to match). In
>   the following example, the asterisk (*) character is inserted before
>   the _ character and designated as an escape character, so that the _
>   character is treated as part of the string to be matched:
>
> comment like ~'%o*_a15progress%~' escape ~'*~'